# Cannot convert object type to string; and then filter on that string; python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pull all stock tickers from NYSE, and then filter out for only those with MarketCap above 5B.

I am running into a problem because based on how my data load comes in all columns are data type "Object" and I cannot find anyway to convert them to anything else. See my code and comments below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# NYSE
url_nyse = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download"
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(url_nyse)
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3, 6,7]], axis=1)
```

This is my initial data load of NYSE stocks, and then I filter for just MarketCap, Sector, and Industry.

At first I was hoping to filter out MarketCap first by anything with "M" in it was removed and then removing the first and last characters to get a number which then could be filtered to keep anything above 5. However I think it is because of the data types being "Object" and not string I have not bee able to do it directly. So I then created new columns that would contain only letters or numbers, hoping that I could then convert to data type string and float from there.

```
df['MarketCap_Num'] = df.MarketCap.str[1:-1]
df['Billion_Filter'] = df.MarketCap.str[-1:]
```

So MarketCap_Num column has only the numbers by removing the first and last characters and Billion_Filter is only the last character where I will remove any value that = M.

However even though these columns are just numbers or just strings I CANNOT find anyway to convert to change from object datatype so then my filtering is not working at all. Any help is much appreciated.

I have tried .astype(float), pd.to_numeric, type functions to no success.

My filtering code would then be:

```
df[df.Billion_Filter.str.contains("B")]
```

But when I run that nothing happens, no error but also no filter happens. When I run this code on a different table it works, so it must be the object data type that is holding it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `MarketCap` column into floats by first removing the dollar signs and then substituting `B` with `e9` and `M` with `e6`. This should make it easy to use `.astype(float)` on the column to do the conversion.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# NYSE
url_nyse = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download"
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(url_nyse)
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3, 6,7]], axis=1)

df = df.replace({'MarketCap': {'\$': '', 'B': 'e9', 'M': 'e6', 'n/a': np.nan}}, regex=True)
df.MarketCap = df.MarketCap.astype(float)

print(df[df.MarketCap > 5000000000].head(10))
```

Yields:

```
           MarketCap             Sector                                         industry
Symbol
MMM     1.419900e+11        Health Care                       Medical/Dental Instruments
WUBA    1.039000e+10         Technology  Computer Software: Programming, Data Processing
ABB     5.676000e+10  Consumer Durables                              Electrical Products
ABT     9.887000e+10        Health Care                            Major Pharmaceuticals
ABBV    1.563200e+11        Health Care                            Major Pharmaceuticals
ACN     9.388000e+10      Miscellaneous                                Business Services
AYI     7.240000e+09  Consumer Durables                                Building Products
ADNT    7.490000e+09      Capital Goods                                Auto Parts:O.E.M.
AAP     7.370000e+09  Consumer Services                           Other Specialty Stores
ASX     1.083000e+10         Technology                                   Semiconductors
```

Comment: This is a very effecient solution, one hangup I am getting is the following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'n/a' since there are some na in the data set; Did you run into this problem? I cant get dropna to work and I dont see any lines about it in your code. Thanks!

Comment: @user2420956, I did not encounter that issue at all. You must be working with an old version of `pandas`. I would recommend you upgrade your pandas installation. Otherwise, please see my edits where I replace `'n/a'` with `np.nan`.

Comment: I did upgrade right now and still got the N/A related error, but your edited version worked. Thanks a ton this took me since 7am EST. Time for me to read up on regex etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the type of the `MarketCap_Num` column by using:

```
df['MarketCap_Num'] = df.MarketCap.str[1:-1].astype(np.float64)
```

You can then check the data types by `df.dtypes`.

As for the filter, you can simple just say

```
df_filtered = df[df['Billion_Filter'] =="B"].copy()
```

since you will only have one letter in your `Billion_Filter` column.

Answer (score 0):

Obhect datatype works as string. You should be able to use both str.contains and extract the number without having to convert the object type to string

```
df = df[df['MarketCap'].str.contains('B')].copy()
df['MarketCap'] = df['MarketCap'].str.extract('(\d+.?\d*)', expand = False)


        MarketCap   Sector          industry
Symbol          
DDD     1.12        Technology      Computer Software: Prepackaged Software
MMM     141.99      Health Care     Medical/Dental Instruments
WUBA    10.39       Technology      Computer Software: Programming, Data Processing
EGHT    1.32        Public UtilitiesTelecommunications Equipment
AIR     1.48        Capital Goods   Aerospace
```

Comment: Ooo... I like the regex usage!